# How to use jQuery Select2 with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I am trying to use jQuery (2.2.1) Select2 (3.5.2) with Angularjs (1.5) but am having a difficult time grabbing the data from the select box.  I have tried [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) and I could retrieve data... but would often crash the browser when searching, was horribly slow and overall unstable (5000-10000 items).  jQuery Select2 is fast and responsive, even with the large number of entries, but I cant seem to get the object when I select an option.

```
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/CustomScripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/select2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".sel").select2();
        });
    </script>
<head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select class="sel" data-ng-model="country.selected" ng-options="country.Name for country in countries | orderBy: 'Name'">
<body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.country = {};

    $scope.countries = [{
        name: 'Australia',
    }, {
        name: 'United States'
    }, {
        name: 'United Kingdom'
    }];

}]);
```

Is there a way to get these two working nicely?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: I've implemented this, but on large lists, it became slow, and would regularly crash browsers.

Comment: How large? I think that the long lists and angular combination is not optimal. That's mean that any angular's plugin for something like this will crushed. Try to move the search to the server.

Comment: For large lists you can fetch the results from the server [async](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select) - I've been working with this modoue and it run smooth, never charshed or anything like that

Comment: There 3 select boxes that reach between 5-10k each

Comment: Each box can select only one choice or its multiselect ?

Comment: Only need single select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching how to access $scope functions from jQuery, I found that using the angular.element.scope().function(x) would allow me to pass the key for each select2 element, on the "change" event, into angular, which can then be manipulated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".sel").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a project..."
        })
        .on("change", function (e) { angular.element(document.getElementById("MainCtrl")).scope().testfunction(); });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular Version of Select2 is available. Check Here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-select2

( The Code is here: https://github.com/rubenv/angular-select2 )

This Angular Library uses Select2 as dependency and helps integrating Select2 in your forms.

Comment: I have tried Angular-Select2, but it suffered from the same performance problems as ui-select, crashing the browser or taking 1+ minutes to load a list of 600-900 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Install via bower "angular-ui-select": "=0.12.1"
Then in your html.....

```
<ui-select multiple
                   class="col-md-8 input-sm"
                   on-select="someMethod()"
                   on-remove="someMethod()"
                   ng-model="country.selected"
                   theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select field...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices
                    repeat="field in countries | filter:$select.search">
                <div ng-bind-html="field.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
```

Never initialize jQuery plugins directly. Search over internet how to integrate jQuery modules with Angular (it might look bit complicated but it's quite easy. Calling it in the way You did will never works....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".sel").select2();
    });
</script>
```

Alternative for ui-select is:

```
angular-chosen ("angular-chosen-localytics": "~1.0.7",)
```

:)

Comment: ui-select is unusable with the number of items I need to populate, its either very slow (30-45 seconds per search) or outright crashes the browser.

Comment: In that case use https://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/. In fact it's tag input but gives You ability to define min and max tags. Support for autocomplite is quite good. Some time ago I replaced all heavy input (with >1k of items).

Comment: Thanks for reference angular-chosen-localytics, but the current version is [1.4.0](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen/releases/tag/1.4.0)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this plugin ,
`ngx-select2`

Add jQuery and Select2 lib

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to add javascript and css libraries  ,  you msust added from `angular.json` example  :

```
 "styles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
      "src/styles.css",
      "src/assets/css/select2.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "src/assets/js/select2.min.js"
    ]
```

Install `ngx-select2`

```
npm i ngx-select2
```

Use select2 component

```
import { LSelect2Module } from 'ngx-select2';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    LSelect2Module
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in html

```
<l-select2 [(ngModel)]="selected" [data]="data" [options]="options" [disabled]="false" (valueChange)="valueChange($event)"></l-select2>
```

**Options**

- data: select2 init data for select
- options: select2 options
- disabled: disable `select2` component
- valueChange: output. Fire on value change, same as `ngModelChange`

Comment: This is an Angular 2+ answer for a question posted as an AngularJS question.